# Understanding unusual behaviour with Java's cyclic inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, package, cyclic

Consider the following two classes `A` and `B` (java) with various package considerations:

#### Both classes in the default package

```
public class A extends B {

  public static class C {}

}

-------------
public class B extends A.C {

  public B() {}

}
```

returns a cyclic inheritance error involving A

#### Class A in package called P1 and Class B in a package called P2

```
package P1;
import P2.B;

public class A extends B {

    public static class C {}

}

--------------
package P2;
import P1.A.C;

public class B extends C {

    public B() {}

}
```

Compiles without error. However, if I change the import statement in class B to `import P1.A` and then change the class definition to `public class B extends A.C` a cycle error shows again.

What explains this behaviour?

Comment: You can't have cyclic dependencies in packages either. Show us your "correct" version.

Comment: This is because all of `A.java` is compiled at once. I believe that to compile C it has to compile A. To compile A it has to first compile B which means it first has to compile C etc.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have edited the question to explain the "correct" behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example there is a cycle for A. 
If `A` extends `B` and `B` extends `C`, since `C` is an inner class in `A` the only way to reference it is to call `A.C`, so java recognises this a cycle on `A`:

`A-->B-->A.C` (`-->` = extends).

In the second example, the cycle is *removed*. By importing `C` through `A`, `B` no longer has to extend `A.C`, but rather simply `C`:

`A-->B-->C`.

So having B in a separate package allows the import of C directly instead of having to call it *through* A.

In example 3 (where we import only `P1.A`), we would still have to refer to `C` as `A.C`, hence the reason the cycle returns.